# Cannot find module 'expect/build/jasmineUtils'

Tags: react-native, jestjs, jasmine

Trying to execute a test suite, I found this error, that reinstalling all the jest-related dependencies doesn't fix it.

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'expect/build/jasmineUtils' from 'node_modules/jest-extended/dist/utils/index.js'

    Require stack:
      node_modules/jest-extended/dist/utils/index.js
      node_modules/jest-extended/dist/matchers/toBeArrayOfSize/index.js
      node_modules/jest-extended/dist/matchers/index.js
      node_modules/jest-extended/dist/index.js

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:425:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-extended/dist/utils/index.js:8:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-extended/dist/matchers/toBeArrayOfSize/index.js:9:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-extended/dist/matchers/index.js:17:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-extended/dist/index.js:3:17)
```

Could be related with it, seems similar: https://github.com/just-jeb/jest-marbles/issues/184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afterward, all were related to some problem that jest have dealing with promises in the last versions.
[Babel problems with the last version of Jest updating ReactNative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75233133/babel-problems-with-the-last-version-of-jest-updating-reactnative)